# Extending a diffeomorphism of $S^1$ to a diffeomorphism of $D^2$ with fourier series.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221688/dm-cup-h-dm-joining-dm-amalg-dm-along-the-boundary-partial-dm?rq=1) and there are some details that are missing. I'm asking for those.

First let $f:S^1\to S^1$ a diffeomorphism. By Dini criterion we can write $f(e^{i\theta})=\sum_n \hat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}$. The above post suggest to define $F:D^2\to D^2$ by $F(re^{i\theta})=\sum_n \hat{f}(n)r^ne^{in\theta}$ for $|r|<1.$  By [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) we have that $F$ is the diffeomorphism that we are looking for.

The problems that I have is with convergence of those series and the fact that $F$ gives values in $D^2
$. The above post suggest to use Cauchy-Schwarz but I don't know how. I also know Parseval's theorem but again, I don't know how to use it. Can someone fill in the details?

EDIT: My question is now, why $F$ lands in $D^2$?

Comment: Think about $(1,re^{i\theta}),r^ e^{i2\theta}, \dots,$ in the $\ell^2$ norm for $r<1$

Comment: @Elad I don't understand.

Comment: To show the series $F$ converges in $\mathbb{C}$ is naive Cauchy-Schwarz: $(\hat{f}(n))$ has $\ell_2$ norm $1$, $(1,z,z^2,\dots)$ has $\ell_2$ norm $1/(1-r^2)$, so their inner product (which is $F$, ok need to flip a conjugate somewhere) is finite.  You still need to show that, in fact $F$ lands in $D^2$.

Comment: $(1,re^{i\theta},r^2 e^{i2\theta}, \dots$ in the $\ell^2$ norm converges for $|r|<1$ hence uniformly convergent on compact sets. Think about Cauchy-Schwarz  in the $\ell^2$ space

Comment: @user10354138 Yes, thanks. Now my problem is about the co-domain of $F.$ It is suficient to show that $F$ lands in a ball in plane and then compose with a diffeo and that the new map that we are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To establish the series $F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\hat{f}(n)z^n$, $z=re^{i\theta}$, actually converges in $\mathbb{C}$, we use Cauchy-Schwarz
$$
\lvert F(z)\rvert^2=\left\lvert\sum_n \hat{f}(n)z^n\right\rvert^2\leq\left(\sum_n\lvert\hat{f}(n)\rvert^2\right)\cdot\left(\sum_n \lvert z^n\rvert^2\right)= 1\cdot\frac{1}{1-r^2}
$$
where the last equality is by Parseval (and summing a geometric series).  So $F(z)\in\mathbb{C}$ for all $z\in D$.

Moreover, $F(z)$ is a nonconstant power series.  As the power series converges for every $z\in S^1$ to the smooth $f\colon S^1\to S^1$, we have $F\in C(D)\cap C^\omega(\mathbb{D})$.  Since $F$ is nonconstant, by the maximum modulus principle, we must have $\lvert F(z)\rvert<\sup_{\lvert\zeta\rvert=1}\lvert F(\zeta)\rvert=1$ for every $z\in\mathbb{D}$.

Finally, $F$ is a diffeomorphism on $\mathbb{D}$: the winding number of $f(e^{it})$, $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$ around any point of $\mathbb{D}$ is clearly $1$, so $F$ is bijective $\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ by argument principle.  Hence $F\colon\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ is univalent.

Comment: Why the winding number of $f$ is 1? and is wrong to use the theorem of Lagrange for inverse?

Comment: $f$ is an orientation-preserving diffeo of $S^1$, so the winding number of $f(S^1)$ is the same as $S^1$.  Lagrange could be used for the inverse but you need to first show it is indeed invertible.  Similarly you could use the same construction for $f^{-1}$ for the inverse.  There are more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, great answer!